# org.jsonexception: value <br> of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: json

hola amigos es mi segunda pregunta en el sitio, y recién estoy empezando en estas lides de android, llevo varios días tratando de solucionar este error y buscando información a través de la web pero no hay nada que me ayude, este el código que utilizo en android.

```
private void buscar_casos (String URL){
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                et_clave.setText(jsonObject.getInt("ID"));
                et_denuncia.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
                et_siniestro.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Siniestro"));
                et_numsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getInt("N_Siniestro"));
                et_descripcion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Descripcion"));
                et_conductor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Conductor"));
                et_rut.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Conductor"));
                et_patente.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Vehiculo"));
                et_tercero.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Tercero"));
                et_patenteter.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Tercero"));
                et_compania.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Compania"));
                et_inspeccion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Inspeccion"));
                et_nombre.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Asegurado"));
                et_rut1.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Asegurado"));
                et_poliza.setText(jsonObject.getInt("N_Poliza"));
                et_causa.setText(jsonObject.getString("Tipo_Seguro"));
                et_analista.setText(jsonObject.getString("Analista"));
                et_perdida.setText(jsonObject.getString("Perdida"));
                et_designacion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Designacion"));
                et_monto.setText(jsonObject.getInt("Monto_Perdida"));
                et_informe.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Informe"));
                et_inspector.setText(jsonObject.getString("Inspector"));
                et_activo.setText(jsonObject.getString("Activo"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener(){
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
);
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

}

y este es el llamado a través del android

```
btn_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        buscar_casos("http://192.168.1.96/oficina/buscar.php?ID ="+et_registro.getText()+"");
    }
});
```

al presionar el boton buscar me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error ahora "error org.jsonexception: value not of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray"

y este es el código que se usa en php

```
<?php
```

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include ("conexion.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

```
$ID = isset($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : '';

$mysqli= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'oficina');
$query = "Select * From casos Where ID = '$ID'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($mysqli -> affected_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
        $casos = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
    }
echo json_encode($casos);
} else {
echo "No se encontraron datos";
}
$result ->close();
$mysqli ->close();
```

}
?>

como pueden ver los códigos sencillos ya que soy nuevo es estas lides, ojala que me puedan ayudar amigos ya que como mencione anteriormente llevo muchos días en esto, además busque a través de este sitio y no hay nada, lo único que mencionan es que es un código HTML insertado, pero no dicen como se soluciona, y no se que mas hacer, y desde ya muchas gracias.